# How to compile firefox nightly on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3b+, archlinux, software-compilation

I am running ArchLinux ARM on the Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I would like to install Firefox nightly on the raspberry pi 3 model B.

I can find similar questions on the internet, but most of the answers/replies to other websites don't really talk about compilation of firefox.

Is there a way to get Firefox Nightly compiled by myself and running on the Raspberry Pi?